# Non-Clustered Indexes in SQL Server - selectivity - and what is in the leaf node page?

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I have two questions about non-clustered indexes in SQL Server, that I can't seem to find the answers for:

1. They say that you should only put a non-clustered index on a column
   with high (e.g. 95%) selectivity (uniqueness of values). Say, for
   example, my MailingAddress table has a column StateID that is a
   foreign key column whose value is the primary key value for the
   State table (we are in the U.S.). There will be a large number of
   records in the MailingAddress table that will have duplicate values
   for this StateID column.  For example, there will be many addresses
   that exist for California, New York state, Texas, etc.  Thus,
   selectivity of the StateID column will be much less than 95%. 
   Should a non-clustered index be placed on this StateID column?
2. I understand that the final, leaf node pages of a clustered index contain the actually the data record itself.

But, what exactly is in the leaf node page of a non-clustered index?  Is it:

1. The clustered index value where the actual record is located? (And then SQL Server will have to look through the clustered index to get the actual record you are looking for)?
2. The actual value of the column(s) that the non-clustered index is on - AND - the value of the clustered index value where the actual record is located (so SQL Server can go look for the values of the other columns of this record that are not part of the non-clustered index)?
3. Something else.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Should a non-clustered index be placed on this StateID column?

No. But non-clustered index with included columns to create a covering index for target query makes plenty of sense.

> But, what exactly is in the leaf node page of a non-clustered index?

The data record. this is an ordinary record, similar to the clustered index data record. It contains the following columns (order is irrelevant):

- the non-clustered index key columns
- the clustered index key columns
- all included columns.

If a column is duplicated in both the non-clustered index (key or included) and in the clustered index key then is only contained once (ie. not duplicated). Some explain this as "all the key columns from the clustered index missing in the non-clustered index" but I found that harder to understand.

If the table does not have a clustered index (ie. is a **heap**) then the record contains:

- all the key columns of the non-clustered index
- all included columns
- the record locator (row id= (fileid:pageid:slotid) ) of the heap record.

This explanation omits columnstore and Hekaton indexes and tables, which are different.

Comment: Remus - thanks a lot of the explanation.  Makes a lot more sense now.